# Why do we use SQLiteCommands instead of string.Format to compose SQL statements?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Many tutorials I've seen compose SQL statements by using variables and `Parameters.Add`, like this:

```
public void updateStudent(String @studentID, String @firstName, String @lastName)
{
    SQLiteCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE Students SET firstName = @firstName, lastName = @lastName WHERE studentID = @studentID";
    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@studentID", @studentID));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@firstName", @firstName));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@lastName" , @lastName));
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Why don't we use

```
string.Format("Update Students SET firstName = '{0}', lastName = '{1}...", @firstName, @lastname)
```

instead?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Four reasons:

- Avoiding [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- Avoiding problems with strings containing *genuine* apostrophes with no intention of causing a SQL injection attack (e.g. a last name of "O'Reilly"
- Avoiding string unnecessary conversions, which can cause failures for cultural reasons (e.g. the difference between "1.23" and "1,23" depending on your culture
- Keeping the code (SQL) and the data (parameters) separate for cleaner readability

Also note:

- This isn't SQLite specific. It's best practice for *all* databases.
- You don't need to use `@` as a prefix to your variables unless they're keywords. So it would be more idiomatic to write:

  ```
  command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@lastName", lastName));
  ```

  (Ditto for the method parameter declarations to start with... but *not* the parameters
  inside the SQL statement.)

Comment: And avoid errors in string quoting just as the OP has done in its example

Comment: It provides an easy and fast way to parameterize queries. This yields bulletproof and simple code that accesses data.

Comment: It provides an easy and fast way to parameterize queries. This yields bulletproof and simple code that accesses data.

Comment: @Steve: I was assuming that the "..." would include the closing quote in the real query. But yes, point taken :)

Comment: Anything placed into a parameter will be treated as field data, not part of the SQL statement, which makes your application much more secure

Comment: @saeed: Isn't that covered by "avoiding SQL injection attacks"?

Comment: @JonSkeet of course it does! but I want to emphasis more on `not a part of SQL statement`