# SQLite select where clause not working when a String value compared with database value in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

The select query is not working in the below case.

```
string sssss = "InspectorADEL2018 -11-13";
con.Open();
String value1 = "select * from finalreport where rmid='"+sssss+"'; ";
SQLiteCommand cmd13 = new SQLiteCommand(value1, con);
dr13 = cmd13.ExecuteReader();
while (dr13.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("The command executed");
}
con.Close();
```

But when we tried the below one the query works and get the output.

```
con.Open();
String value1 = "select * from finalreport where rmid='InspectorADEL2018 -11-13'; ";
SQLiteCommand cmd13 = new SQLiteCommand(value1, con);
dr13 = cmd13.ExecuteReader();
while (dr13.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("The command executed");
}
con.Close();
```

How can I solve the problem when we assign the value to a string variable?

Comment: you need to escape the `-` chars

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615113/how-to-escape-special-characters-like-in-sqlite-in-android

Comment: I think this kind of problem would be avoided by using query parameters instead of building the SQL via string concatenation. Please have a look at this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017688/why-we-do-sqlitecommand-parameters-add-while-we-can-use-string-format-to-compos

Comment: cant do because  -  is in date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me

```
string sssss = "InspectorADEL2018 -11-13";
ssss = ssss.Replace("\n", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

> DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(String)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils